# Ubuntu-Server router - forwarding/routing does not work

Tags: ubuntu, routing, forwarding

This is more or less a pretty general question about forwarding and routing with ubuntu server or any linux system, i guess.

The server manages a school network and has 8 NICs - each on a different network.

- 7 leading to different classrooms.
- 1 leading into the network, that contains other servers (print server, domain controller, etc ..)

  - finally this network has the  another gateway in that network leads to the internet.

I want to:

- forward the traffic coming from the 7 classrooms to the network that contains the other servers/that leads to the internet
- forward some traffic the other way round (e.g. print-server to printers in classrooms)

I do not want to:

- configure NAT
- edit every routing-table on every single client-PC in the classrooms.

As I understood it, just enabling net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 via sysctl and sysctl.conf should have done the trick .. But it didn't.

After reading and trying out a lot of different stuff, I tried the following iptables-rule.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

eth0 being the network leading to the other servers and the internet.
And that worked .. but this is a NAT rule.

So my big question is: 
Is there a way at all to do it without the NAT-rule?
Or:
What does it take, to do it without the NAT-rule?

Comment: Doesn't every client beyond the router have a private ip address like 192.168.7.52 or is that really something like 92.17.1.22?

Comment: What didn't work? What is your routing table?

Comment: I had to keep the NAT-Rule and add a static route back to every class-network on the print-server. Maybe I should do that for every server in the eth0-network, because a) there aren't many servers and b) that internet-facing gateway will sooner or later be replaced by that linux-box. So both TheCompWiz and Zoredache were right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a relatively simple setup... and linux can handle this without any troubles.

You're probably suffering from one or two problems.

1) No return routes to this "router".

For a router to do its job properly... every device needs to have a route to that router.  (either directly attached... or attached to another router that knows about it.)

[image: No Return Route]

You can fix this relatively simply by adding a return route in the "Internet Router" of all networks attached to the "Linux Router".  There are routing protocols that can do this for you automagically but in small-ish environments (such as this) they're generally much more work than it's worth.

2) Mixing private and public address space.  Once your packet leaves the public internet space... it better have the source NATed with a public IP... or be legitimately from a public IP.  [Private network addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) are not routable from the public Internet.

[image: Private Networks]

The only way to get around this is to NAT or assign public address space to your network.  NATing is relatively simple and secure... public address space can be very dangerous, as every machine would become a target of hackers.

Comment: I kept the NAT-rule, as you suggested. Then added the missing routes (from the server-network at eth0 back to the classroom-networks). So yes, this was very helpful (which I would love to express by one-upping it on the left - but I'm not allowed to, since I'm too new, here).

Answer (score 0):

> configure NAT

Not required

> edit every routing-table on every single client-PC in the classrooms.

Changing routes on the client machines behind the linux router will not do anything useful.  The problem is on the hosts on the server network don't know how to reply.

> and finally another gateway in that network leads to the internet.

I bet that all your systems on the server network have their default gateway pointed at the border router that gets them external access instead of this new linux box.

So your problem is that the devices on the server network have no idea how to get to the other networks behind this new linux router.  The only route they have points to the border router that gets them external access, and nothing else

- The best fix is to add routes to the static routes on the border router.
- If you can't add static routes on the border router

  - Get a better router
  - Put your server network on another network behind your hub router.
  - You could adjust the default gateway of everything on the server network to point at your hub router.
  - You could add additional static routes on every device on the 'server network' but that would be the wrong solution.

Comment: My question was not only about internet access, but also/mostly about the "server network" at eth0. So the solution to my problem was to add additional routes to our print-server (which was acting up most of all) back to all the classroom-networks. So your bet was correct.